# R: weighted aggregation

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset on this form:

```
set.seed(4561)    # Make the results reproducible

df=data.frame(
colour=rep(c("green","red","blue"),each=3),
year=rep("2017",9),
month=rep(c(1,2,3),3),
price=c(200,254,188,450,434,490,100,99,97),
work=ceiling(runif(9,30,60)),
gain=ceiling(runif(9,1,10)),
work_weighed_price=NA,
gain_weighed_price=NA
)
```

For each colour, year, month I have a price (output variable) and two input variables called gain and work. In reality I have many more input variables, but this suffices to show what I desire to do with my dataframe.

```
> df
  colour year month price work gain work_weighed_price gain_weighed_price
1  green 2017     1   200   33    9                 NA                 NA
2  green 2017     2   254   56    5                 NA                 NA
3  green 2017     3   188   42    8                 NA                 NA
4    red 2017     1   450   39    3                 NA                 NA
5    red 2017     2   434   45    2                 NA                 NA
6    red 2017     3   490   36    8                 NA                 NA
7   blue 2017     1   100   50    8                 NA                 NA
8   blue 2017     2    99   45    8                 NA                 NA
9   blue 2017     3    97   56    4                 NA                 NA
```

I wish to calculate the weighted gain and work (and also the weighted price), where the weight is the price for that month and year, divided by the sum of price across colours:

```
 desired_output=data.frame(
  year=rep("2017",3),
  month=rep(c(1,2,3),1),
  price=c(200*(200/(200+450+100))+450*(450/(200+450+100))+100*(100/(200+450+100)),
          254*(254/(254+434+99))+434*(434/(254+434+99))+99*(99/(254+434+99)),
          188*(188/(188+490+97))+490*(490/(188+490+97))+97*(97/(188+490+97))),
  work_weighed_price=c(47*(200/(200+450+100))+44*(450/(200+450+100))+52*(100/(200+450+100)),
                       44*(254/(254+434+99))+42*(434/(254+434+99))+32*(99/(254+434+99)),
                       38*(188/(188+490+97))+52*(490/(188+490+97))+52*(97/(188+490+97))) ,                                      
  gain_weighed_price=c(5*(200/(200+450+100))+8*(450/(200+450+100))+10*(100/(200+450+100)),
                       3*(254/(254+434+99))+7*(434/(254+434+99))+9*(99/(254+434+99)),
                       2*(188/(188+490+97))+4*(490/(188+490+97))+9*(97/(188+490+97)))
)

> desired_output
  year month    price work_weighed_price gain_weighed_price
1 2017     1 336.6667           45.86667           7.466667
2 2017     2 333.7649           41.38755           5.960610
3 2017     3 367.5523           48.60387           4.140645
```

How would I attack this in R?

Comment: Where do the weights of `work_weighed_price`, the numbers `47, 44, 52` for the first, and the same for the others, come from? They do not come from column `work`. And what about `gain_weighed_price`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I'm so, so sorry! I forgot to use set.seed when making the data! :( I will edit the whole thing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `weighted.mean` function

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(price, work, gain), 
               funs(price_weighted = weighted.mean(., price)))
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   year [?]
#    year month price_price_weighted work_price_weighted gain_price_weighted
#    <int> <int>                <dbl>               <dbl>               <dbl>
# 1  2017     1                  337                45.9                7.47
# 2  2017     2                  334                41.4                5.96
# 3  2017     3                  368                48.6                4.14
```

Or, in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, lapply(.SD, weighted.mean, price)
   , .SDcols = c('price', 'work', 'gain')
   , by = .(year, month)]

#    year month    price     work     gain
# 1: 2017     1 336.6667 45.86667 7.466667
# 2: 2017     2 333.7649 41.38755 5.960610
# 3: 2017     3 367.5523 48.60387 4.140645
```

Comment: Very nice :) could you explain what the "funs()" does?

Comment: inside `funs`, you can define functions in shorthand where e.g. `weighted mean(., price)` is equivalent to `function(x) weighted mean(x, price)` in base R. These functions will be applied to the variables specified in the first argument of `summarise_at`. The output of the functions will be named as the original variables with the name you gave the function appended.

Comment: This is a more elegant solution -- @Erosennin, you should consider accepting this answer instead.

Comment: Done! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

An approach using `dplyr`. Your use of `runif` in your example `df` without setting seed and the fact that it doesn't line up with your desired output is causing some confusion. In the code below, I use a `df` that's consistent with your desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(year, month) %>%
  mutate(weight = price / sum(price)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(price, work, gain), funs(weighed_price = . * weight)) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(ends_with("weighed_price")), sum)
# # A tibble: 3 x 5
# # Groups:   year [?]
#    year month work_weighed_price gain_weighed_price price_weighed_price
#   <int> <int>              <dbl>              <dbl>               <dbl>
# 1  2017     1               45.9               7.47                337.
# 2  2017     2               41.4               5.96                334.
# 3  2017     3               48.6               4.14                368.
```

`df`:

```
structure(list(colour = c("green", "green", "green", "red", "red", 
"red", "blue", "blue", "blue"), year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L), month = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), price = c(200L, 254L, 188L, 450L, 
434L, 490L, 100L, 99L, 97L), work = c(47L, 44L, 38L, 44L, 42L, 
52L, 52L, 32L, 52L), gain = c(5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 10L, 9L, 
9L), work_weighed_price = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), gain_weighed_price = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("colour", 
"year", "month", "price", "work", "gain", "work_weighed_price", 
"gain_weighed_price"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Comment: Thank you much! Yes, I forgot set.seed, sorry about that, and thank you for seeing through it!
I'm not familiar with dplyr, but it looks very elegant! Could I ask, where do you add the postfix "weighed price" ? Is it at the mutate_at step?

Comment: I see that this line: "mutate_at(vars(price, work, gain), funs(weighed_price = . * weight))" make the new columns, but I do not see the logic behind the notation inside "funs". How does it understand to add "weighed_price" behind variables inside var() ?

Comment: @Erosennin: naming the function inside `funs()` will append the function name to the original variables. See examples in `?mutate_at`.

Answer (score 2):

A base R solution could be the following sequence of `tapply` instructions.

```
fun_price <- function(x){
    s <- sum(x)
    sum(x*(x/s))
}

fun_weighted <- function(x, w){
    s <- sum(w)
    sum(x*(w/s))
}

desired <- data.frame(year = unique(df$year), month = sort(unique(df$month)))

desired$price <- with(df, tapply(price, month, FUN = fun_price))
desired$work_weighed_price <- with(df, tapply(work, month, FUN = fun_weighted, w = price))
desired$gain_weighed_price <- with(df, tapply(gain, month, FUN = fun_weighted, w = price))

desired
#  year month    price work_weighed_price gain_weighed_price
#1 2017     1 336.6667           40.74092           6.622405
#2 2017     2 333.7649           48.56834           4.984429
#3 2017     3 367.5523           44.65052           6.659170
```

Comment: Very elegant, thank you very much! I did not actually see this answer before just now! Very grateful!

Comment: what if there were more groups, could you still use tapply, then? I tried with "...tapply(price, c(year,month), FUN=fun_price))" and it gave me an error.

Comment: @Erosennin I would have to see. But whenever there is a year/month problem, the standard trick is to use package `zoo`, function `as.yearmon`. Maybe in this case it is not needed, maybe to use `paste(year, month)` as aggregation variable will do it.